# Is this predicate expressing compactness?

Tags: general-topology, logic, definition

I don't quite know why definitions of "compact" use the expression "arbitrary collection".

Am I correct in thinking that the following predicate is a definition of compact?

Let $X$ by a set with topology $\mathcal T$,

$\mathrm{compact}(X):=\forall (Y\subset \mathcal T).\ \exists (k\in\mathbb N).\ \exists (f:\{0,1,2,\dots,k\}\to \mathcal T).\ Y\subset\mathrm{im}(f)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It can't possibly be correct because the right-hand side of the definition omits $X$.

You also need the codomain of $f$ to be $Y$, not $\mathcal T$. Compactness doesn't say that a set has a finite covering (which every set trivially has); it says that every covering has a finite *sub*-covering.

Also you have the types mixed up. On the left, $Y$ is a family of open sets.  On the right, you claim that $Y$ is a subset of the image of $f$.  But this is certainly not true in general, since $Y$ could be an infinite family, but the image of $f$ is the finite set $\{f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(n)\}$.  I think what you're getting at is that $\bigcup Y\subset \bigcup_i f(i)$, but even this isn't quite what you want.

Try this: If $C$ is an open covering of $X$, that's  $X\subset \bigcup C $ where $C\subset\mathscr T$, then there is a finite subcovering $S\subset C$ that also covers $X$, so $X\subset \bigcup S$.  Try this: $$ \forall C\subset{\mathcal T}.\left( X\subset \bigcup C \implies \exists S\subset C . \text{$S$ is finite and }X\subset \bigcup S\right).$$

You can replace “$S$ is finite” with some squiggle-squoggle involving functions from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, but I don't see the benefit.

Comment: +1, okay thanks, I see that a) I should write union of im(f) and also b) already choose Y to be subset of a covering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$$ \forall (Y\subset \mathcal T)\colon \bigcup Y=X\to \exists (k\in\mathbb N)\exists (f\colon\{1,\ldots, k\}\to Y)\colon\bigcup \operatorname{im}f=X$$

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite know how you want to parse the $=$ here though, I use other notation. In any case, this should work too, right?: $\forall (\mathcal{T'} \subseteq \mathcal{T}). (K\subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{T'} \implies\ \exists (k\in\mathbb N).\ \exists (f:\{1,2,\dots,k\}\to \mathcal T).\ K\subset \bigcup \mathrm{im}(f)$

Comment: I don't think you want $\bigcup Y = X$ on the left side there.  For example in $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and $X = (-\infty,1]$, there is no such $Y$, so your claim is vacuously true. But $(-\infty, 1]$ is not compact.  You need $\bigcup Y\supset X$, and similarly on the right $\bigcup\operatorname{im} f \supset X$.